# slow input on database SQlite3 python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to save username on local sqlite3 db using python. I am really new. My Table has 10000 rows and just a column of username but it is taking more than half an hour to inset all 10k values. What is I am doing wrong ? Is there any clue ? My code

```
 def create_table(channel_username):
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(user_name UNIQUE)".format(channel_username))
    conn.commit()


def insert_username(channel_username,user_name):
    c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {} VALUES(?)".format(channel_username),[user_name])
    conn.commit()


create_table(channel_username)

x= client.get_participants(channel_username, aggressive=True)

z=[]
for user in x:

    z.append(user.username)

fl = [i for i in z if i is not None]

fl.sort()

for user_name in fl:

    insert_username(channel_username,user_name)

print("DBfached successful")
```

Comment: Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite) will give you some pointers. The python sqlite bindings don't have the features or power of the C API, but there's still stuff you can take away from it. Start with transactions, and also read up on the `executemany()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The inserts are not slow; all the `commit()` calls are slow.

Remove them, and do the `commit()` only when you're actually finished.